# What is the distance limit for Continuous Cluster Replication?

Tags: cluster

I have heard there is a limit to the distance which you can get Continuous Cluster Replication to work properly.  Anyone have any insight on this?  If so, What is the latency threshold where the CCR capability begins to break down?

Assuming ideal conditions, what is the largest distance I could separate my clusters geographically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some NetApp documents talk about this subject.  Then indicate that Exchange 2007 requires disk latency below 20ms which usually translates to about 100 miles

http://partners.netapp.com/go/techontap/matl/exchange2007.html

> **Distance to the disaster recovery
>   site.** Remember that Microsoft
>   Geographically Dispersed Clusters
>   require network latency below 500ms,
>   and Exchange 2007 requires a disk
>   latency below 20ms, which typically
>   restricts distances less than 100
>   miles between systems in the cluster.
>   If the DR site is more than 100 miles
>   away, then a solution other than or in
>   addition to CCR is required.

Comment: That is precisely what I needed to know!  Thank you....